# Google Authentication Failing on TravisCI build, asking for clientID

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, passport.js, travis-ci, google-oauth

I wrote a passport google sign-in code to enable users to sign in to an app with Google plus. The app works on my device but when I push it to Github for Travis to build, I get a type error that goes like this

```
TypeError: OAuth2Strategy requires a clientID option
    at Strategy.OAuth2Strategy (/home/travis/build/devcareer/Dae-Alright-Backend/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:86:34)
    at new Strategy (/home/travis/build/devcareer/Dae-Alright-Backend/node_modules/passport-google-oauth20/lib/strategy.js:52:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/travis/build/devcareer/Dae-Alright-Backend/src/config/passport-config/google-passport-config.js:1:5044)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1121:30)
    at Module.replacementCompile (/home/travis/build/devcareer/Dae-Alright-Backend/node_modules/append-transform/index.js:58:13)
```

The thing is the clientID is already provided in my code below.

```
import { config } from 'dotenv';
import passport from 'passport';
import GoogleStrategy from 'passport-google-oauth20';
import database from '../../database/models';

import { findBySocialID } from './config';

const { User } = database;
config();

passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
  // options
  clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
  clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
  callbackURL: '/auth/google/redirect',
},
(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
  try {
    findBySocialID(profile.id, 'google').then(async currentUser => {
      if (currentUser) {
        return done(null, currentUser);
      }
      const user = {
        socialID: profile.id,
        provider: 'google',
        firstName: profile.name.givenName,
        lastName: profile.name.familyName,
        email: profile.emails[0].value,
        phone: '',
        address: '',
      };
      await User.create(user);
      return done(null, user);
    });
  } catch (err) {
    done(err, false);
  }
},),);

export default passport;
```

I'm confused at this point. It works locally but fails to build with TravisCI.

Comment: Perhaps TravisCI does not have access to the environment variables

Comment: Yeahh... Thanks for the idea, That was the issue. Resolved using this resource: https://medium.com/@pelensky/environment-variables-in-travis-ci-2c5bce1b01d8